# How do you find the intersection of the rational numbers, and in interval of irrational numbers?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Take for example $Q ∩ [ - \sqrt(2) , \sqrt (2)]$? Would it be $[ - \sqrt(2) , \sqrt (2)]$ or is this untrue since they are not in $Q$?

Comment: It wouldn't be the $[-\sqrt2, \sqrt2]$ since that contains (uncountably many) irrational numbers. Usually we just write the intersection of $Q$ with an interval as exactly that.

Comment: Find it? When was it lost? It's thoroughly and completely defined and described as it is "the rational numbers between negative sqrt 2 and sqrt 2".  That's utterly clear and nothing more needs to be said. The only thing to discuss is that the end points aren't in it and if you a presuming that Q is you universal set you don't have to state the intersect.  But then you should call the end points by sqrt 2.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it cannot be $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$ as the endpoints are not rationals. Your question is not exactly clear, the set you have mentioned is closed in the rationals, that's all I can say for now.

Answer (score 1):

It would usually be written $$\mathbb{Q} \cap [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$$
That is equal to $$\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$$ because $\sqrt{2} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Note that this is not $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$ because (for example) $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is in the interval $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ but is not rational.

The set can also be written $$\{ x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 < 2\}$$ if you want to stay entirely within the rationals.